# Accessing List Of Class Objects

Tags: python, list, object, user-interface, a-star

I am still a beginner when it comes to programming, and am wondering what is wrong with my program (A* Pathfinder Algorithm GUI). I have been trying to debug for several days now, and it keeps giving me the "calculateSurroundingHeuristic() error" when I am trying to print gridRowList[0][0]. My program takes 4 inputs through the GUI: start and end x & y values. GridRowList is just a list which I have created by appending 50 rows of 50 pixels inside each row.

The following are my global variables and the Pixel Class

```
#Define global variables
x1_int = 0
y1_int = 0
x2_int = 0
y2_int = 0
startPixel = None
endPixel = None
gridList = 0
gridRowList = 0

class Pixel:
    def __init__(self, x, y, heuristic):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.heuristic = heuristic

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.getCoordinate() + "H = " + str(self.getHeuristic()))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def getCoordinate(self):
        return (str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y))

    def getx(self):
        return self.x

    def gety(self):
        return self.y

    def getHeuristic(self):
        return int(self.heuristic)

    def get(self):
        return self

    def updateHeuristic(self, new_heuristic):
        self.heuristic = new_heuristic

    def calculatePixelHeuristic(self, x2_int, y2_int):

        local_x = int(self.getx())
        local_y = int(self.gety())

        local_x_differential = int(abs(local_x - x2_int))

        print(local_x_differential)

        local_y_differential = int(abs(local_y - y2_int))
        
        print(local_y_differential)



        local_heuristic = int(math.sqrt((local_x_differential ** 2) + (local_y_differential ** 2)))

        return local_heuristic 

def calculateSurroundingHeuristic(x1_int, y1_int, x2_int, y2_int):

    rowNumber = int(y1_int)
    columnNumber = int(x1_int) 
    listofMoves = []

    try:
        #R-1, C-1
        newRow = int(rowNumber) - 1
        newColumn = int(columnNumber) - 1

        #TEST
        global gridRowlist
        print(gridRowlist[0][0])
        print(gridRowList[newRow][newColumn])

        #find a way here to access a pixel based on coordinates in the gridRowlist and modify its heuristic
        #gridRowList[rowNumber]

    except:
        #TEST
        print("calculateSurroundingHeuristic() error")
        pass
```

After this, they are appended to a list called rowList, and are appended in 50 rows of 50 pixels. This is what happens after:

## Append items to gridRowList & populate GUI grid

```
    tempString = "r"
for i in range(1, 51):
    tempString = tempString + str(i)
    gridRowList.append(eval(tempString))
    tempString = "r"
```

Comment: You haven't actually *defined* any global variables. You've merely used the `global` statement, which is actually quite pointless in the global scope.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Fixed, but problem is the same

Comment: What is the error you are getting? You **must** provide a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, provide the *full error message including the stack trace* "calculateSurroundingHeuristic() error" is not a Python error.

Comment: Whenever I try executing the line print(gridRowlist[0][0]), it does not print, and since it is in a try-except clause, it will print me the error message of calculateSurroundingHeuristic() error which is triggered by the except clause. Not a python error, I am not getting the value I expect.